# removing columns with pandas from csv - not found in axis

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove 1 column from .csv but I'm receiving an error.

```py
import pandas as pd
df.drop("First Invoice #", axis = 1, inplace= True)
```

```
KeyError: "['First Invoice #'] not found in axis"
```

Here you find file .csv
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q1_PByc-xaFOc47Fg9bGLOj6jsMGIxJx/view?usp=sharing

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you for your help
Angelo

Comment: I solved with this:  #remove all rows with "hello"
df = df.drop(df.index[df['Shp.Type desc.'] == 'Hello'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your data is separated by semicolon instead of comma. Use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', sep=';')
```

Demonstration:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', sep=';')
df.drop("First Invoice #", axis = 1, inplace= True)
df
```

Output:

[image]

You can use `del` too:

```
del df["First Invoice #"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Mustansir is right, you can try changing your code with

```
import pandas as pd
df.drop("First Invoice #", axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

If you refer to the pandas documentation for [DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), you can see that `axis = 0` refers to the index (row) while `axis = 1` refers to the columns, and by default, the function is dropping by the index.

The `pd.drop()` function is preferred as it also deletes the instance instead of the just the name.